# Finding number of days in month from a text file without using "if"

Tags: python

Write the number of days in months program so that the program prompts the user for the file name and reads the dates from the file.

The dates in the file are written in the format dd.mm.yyyy. The program looks for the month in each line (hint: use split) and prints out the number of days in that month.

Rewrite the function so that it does not contain conditional (if) statements for returning the number of days. The function should do it using a list. Do not add the check for a leap year (let’s say that there are 28 days in February).

I have this code:

```
dates = {}

file = input("Enter file name:")

file = open("dates.txt", "r")

for line in file:

  month = line.split(".")

  dates = month[1]

print (dates)
```

But it only reads the month from the text file. How do I add another formula to read the months and state the days instead, within this code without using "IF"?

Comment: See also: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/798371)

Answer (score 0):

It's only reading months because of this line:

```
dates = month[1]
```

which selects the array element at index 1 from the array created by `split`.  Since array indicies start counting at 0, that's the second element, which is the month (according to the specified date format). You can use the month number to index into a list to get the number of days that month has, like `daysInMonth[dates]` where you've predefined `daysInMonth`.  That definition should go before any time when you use it, and it only needs to be defined once so it can be defined outside of any loop.

Your code might be more readable if you swapped the variable names `dates` and `month`.

Comment: I want the code to read the month from the file (let's say month 10) and state the days of that month, which is, 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a dictionary dictDates={1:31, 2:28, 3:31, 4:30, ...} or a listDates=list [31, 28, 31, 30, ...]

And with the month get the value for the number of days from there dictDates[date] or listDates[date-1]

[Edit with full code]

```
file = input("Enter file name: ")
file = open("dates.txt", "r")

dictDates={'1':31, '2':28, '3':31, '4':30, ...}

for line in file:
  month = line.split(".")[1]
  print(dictDates[month])
```

Comment: Yeah, I mean where do I add it? I'm trying to but all comes in error.

Comment: I'd write this that way :)

file = input("Enter file name: ")
file = open("dates.txt", "r")

dictDates={'1':31, '2':28, '3':31, '4':30, ...}

for line in file:
  month = line.split(".")[1]
  print(dictDates[month])

Answer (score 0):

you can map the month name (or numeric value) to a number associated with the number of days in that month. So something like

```
monthToDay = {1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30, 7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31}
```

then the days in each month is just the value in the dictionary at the months location.

```
monthToDay[date]
```